# config.xml file is reset to default values when "ionic run android" command is runed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

i am using ionic 2 and when i try to to edit the config.xml file to tweak to splash screen preference to my taste and i save it but when i run "ionic run android" the config.xml file is beign reset to default values...so all my modifications are los and they are not also implimented in the .apk file. so why is this happening

Default values

```html
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000" />
```

my modification

```html
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="500" />
```

after i run the "ionic run/build android" command

```html
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000" />
```

why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the minimum amount of seconds for a Splashscreen, maybe try it on another project. Good Luck!

Comment: no that is not it, i found the problem i was editing the config.xml which is automatically generated anytime a build command is runed. instead edit the one found in the www folder that is the one that is used to generate the previous one i editing found in the android platform folder

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<platform name="android">

    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />        
</platform>
```